# Press e-mail and open the default e-mail client

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am develop an UWP app, using Template 10, and in section "About" I have my e-mail (textblock) for the users contact me! I would like users to press to my e-mail and open the default e-mail client and send me an e-mail.
It is possible?

Comment: LaunchUriAsync() with "mailto:"

Comment: LaunchUriAsync() is a event handler?
My e-mail is in a textblock

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app#email-uri-scheme

Comment: I put LaunchUriAsync () in my XAML and mailto: in C # right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

Use `HyperlinkButton` instead of `TextBlock`

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="emailaddress@outlook.com" NavigateUri="mailto:emailaddress@outlook.com"/>
```

**Method 2**

If you want to use `TextBlock` then use `Tapped` event in it.

In XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="emailaddress@outlook.com" Tapped="TextBlock_TappedAsync" />
```

In Code Behind

```
private async void TextBlock_TappedAsync(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:emailaddress@outlook.com"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used 2º method

Answer (score 2):

You should use a button rather than TextBlock. 
Here is the sample code which you can add as click event or command:

```
private async Task ComposeEmail()
    {
        var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
        emailMessage.Body = "Hello, this is sample email body.";

        var emailRecipient = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient("some@email.com");
        emailMessage.To.Add(emailRecipient);

        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
    }
```